# Android:Is it advisable to use dp to specify size of UI elements?

Tags: android, android-layout, pixel-density

Is using dp alone good enough to ensure that the size of the UI elements will be consistent aross all screen sizes and densities? Or do we have to use Linear Layout's weightSum feature to ensure a more consistent result?

Comment: Specifying the size of UI elements in dp is recommended and will make the physical size consistent regardless of resolution. If you want "consistent" layout between different screen sizes, then you layout weights might be a better choice. Best would be to specify different layouts for each supported screen size to make best use of the real estate available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Depending on what you try to accomplish: dp will ensure the same size across screens, and weights (or percent in the android support library) will keep its ratios.

- If you want 3 columns of the same width you use *weights* for an equal distribution
- If you have an icon, or a button you use *dp* to ensure the same actual size on all devices

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. If you want to have same look and feel on different screen resolutions . it is a relative measure hence it calculates how much pixels to take on different screens whereas pixels are absolute. For consistent Ui and user experience its recommended.